# Regarding the Weibull Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

So I'm plotting a Weibull RV . The PDF is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
B \, x^{B-1} e^{-x\,B} , & \text{if } x \ge 0\\
0,  & \text{elsewhere} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now when $B=0.5$ and $x=0$, what will my $f(x)$ be?

Basically, I get 0^(something) . Does this count as infinity considering 0^(-0.5) can be written as (1/(0^0.5)) ?

P.S. how does one write the math equations on this forum? With standard symbols and notations? I'm a noob and I'd be grateful of somebody pointed out where to go regarding directions about posting here.

Comment: You might want to read the [help page on notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shape parameter ($B$ in your expression) is between $0$ and $1$ then the density increases without limit as $x$ decreases towards $0$.

The best thing to do is decide what density is high enough to illustrate this, and then not plot for smaller values of $x$ which give a higher density than this.  For example the [Wikipedia article on the Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) does not bother with densities above $2.5$ when plotting the blue line, which is the one you want, as it uses $k$ as the shape parameter

[image: Wikipedia - Weibull distribution]